# Definition of a scalar function on the $n$-sphere and its derivative for obtaining a vector field on $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields, spheres

Is it possible to define scalar function on the surface of a sphere? For instance, define a function
$$
f\colon\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}, \quad
\mathbf{x}\mapsto\exp\left(-\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert^2\right).
$$
In a sense that $f$ "bends" the sphere inside around $\mathbf{x}_0$.

Does this even make sense? How could the gradient of such function be calculated on $\mathbb{S}^n$?

**EDIT:** I'm updating this question to ask for guidelines on how to calculate the gradient of $f$ on $\mathbb{S}^n$. In fact, I have no idea where to look at, could you please help?

My goal is to define a vector field on $\mathbb{S}^n$ such, that given any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{S}^n$, to be able to assign a vector $\mathbf{v}_x$ to $\mathbf{x}$ and use it in order to calculate a $\mathbf{x}^\prime=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v}_x$ and project it back on $\mathbb{S}^n$. I'm not sure whether the gradient of $f$ could be used for such purpose, any insight on this will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This is completely valid. To compute the gradient it is helpful to locally parametrize the sphere using coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon thanks for your comment! Would it make sense to apply the function to the Euclidean space and "go back" to sphere using the inverse stereographic projection? I understand this is very different than what you proposed (I just thought it and figured I could ask). Also, would you think that spherical coordinates could apply here? I feel that's something "easier" due to the square norm in $\exp()$. Thanks for your time in any case.

Comment: Hmm, it isn't my intuition that stereographic projection will play nice with derivatives, in the sense that the resulting computation may be painful.  Maybe the better approach is to first compute the gradient considering $f$ as a function on the entirety of Euclidean space, and then restrict the gradient to the sphere by only allowing dot products with vectors tangent to the sphere.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon I see, many thanks for your answers.

Comment: Orthogonal project the usual gradient to the tangent hyperplane.